# Use var in field declaration

Tags: java, local-variables, java-10

So starting in Java 9, we can use var to declare local variables:

```
var s = "cool";
```

is there a way to use a similar construct when declaring fields?

```
class Container {
  final var s = "cool"; // does not compile tmk
}
```

doesn't seem like it from what I can tell.

Comment: *starting in Java 9* ... No, `var` was introduced in Java-10

Answer (score 8):

> is there a way to use a similar construct when declaring fields?

No.

According to [JEP 286: Local-Variable Type Inference](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286):

> This treatment would be restricted to local variables with initializers, indexes in the enhanced for-loop, and locals declared in a traditional for-loop; it would ***not be available for*** method formals, constructor formals, method return types, **fields**, catch formals or any other kind of variable declaration.

Answer (score 5):

No, [there is not](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9).

> `var` is not a keyword, but rather an identifier with special meaning
>   as the type of a local variable declaration (§14.4, §14.14.1,
>   §14.14.2, §14.20.3).

`var` can only be used in [local variable declaration statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4) with the syntax

```
LocalVariableDeclarationStatement:
    LocalVariableDeclaration ;
LocalVariableDeclaration:
    {VariableModifier} LocalVariableType VariableDeclaratorList
LocalVariableType:
    UnannType 
    var
```

[Field declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-FieldDeclaration) do not contain syntax where the `var` special identifier is allowed:

```
FieldDeclaration:
    {FieldModifier} UnannType VariableDeclaratorList ;
```