# What's the point of repeating the class named when defining a new class instance?

Tags: java

Given the Java class **City**.

What is the point of writing `City springfield = new City();`

Instead of `springfield = new City();`

Comment: to make it compile?

Comment: to know what `springfield `is supposed to be?

Comment: @jhamon If we assign the variable a new instance of a class City, why would it be something different than City?

Comment: It can also be an interface City implements

Comment: why would you assign a `City`and not an `int`in the first place? Because you said `springfield`is a `City`

Comment: Suppose City extends 'Location', then is springfield a City, or a Location ?

Comment: @AlvaroFranz yes, it could be `HumanSettlement springfield = new City();` where `City` is a subclass of `HumanSettlement`

Comment: @Arnaud I don't know yet what interface type is, because I just started learning, so I guess that will be the answer to my question. Thank you.

Comment: Because you should specify the type of the Instance or a higher type or an interface that the class implements.

Comment: @AlvaroFranz `City springfield` is just a reference on the stack. To create an object you have to use `new ClassName()` where the `new` operator dynamically allocates the memory on the heap and then constructor is called. So basically you declare the reference of some type (`City` in this case)  and then you create an object itself. That is why you have to repeat class name - 1)to create the reference and 2) to create the object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no point, [since Java 10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49598148/545127), [for local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54662190/use-var-in-field-declaration). For local variables you can instead write:

```
var springfield = new City();
```

Also, you can create an object *without* introducing an object reference, if you create an object in an expression. Typically this is done in a method call:

```
settlements.add(new City());
```

You must still repeat the class name for attributes (fields).

But, there is an exception to this. If you want to [program to an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface), you must indicate the type of object you are constructing *and* the interface class you want the [object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766681/what-is-the-difference-between-an-object-reference-id-and-reference-variable) to have:

```
Settlement springfield = new City();
```